# Do I need to explicitly check for __name__ == "__main__" before calling getLogger in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I believe it's standard practice when using Python's built-in logging module to have the `logger` in the main module be the root logger. Assuming this is correct, it seems to me that for any module that may or may not be run as main I need to explicitly check. The reason is that if I follow the standard practice of calling `logging.getLogger(__name__)` I'll get a logger named `__main__` rather than the root logger:

```
import logging
print logging.getLogger().name # root
print logging.getLogger(__name__).name # __main__
```

Is the best practice always to check?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger()
else:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This is not so bad because I'll always have other code that only runs if `__name__ == "__main__"` (often including a call to `logging.basicConfig`) but it would be nice to need only one line instead of more.

Comment: Python has a ternary, y'know. So you could do something like: `logger = logging.getLogger(*([__name__] if __name__ != '__main__' else []))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice of using `logging.getLogger(__name__)` is meant for a *module-level logger*, as explained in the 
[advanced logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial).

In a script (or the main module of an application) I generally don't create a logger at all, but I do change the configuration of the root logger;

```
opts = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='foo', description=__doc__)
group.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version',
                   version=__version__)
opts.add_argument('--log', default='warning',
                  choices=['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error'],
                  help="logging level (defaults to 'warning')")
opts.add_argument("files", metavar='file', nargs='*',
                  help="one or more files to process")
args = opts.parse_args(argv)
logging.basicConfig(level=getattr(logging, args.log.upper(), None),
                    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
```

Comment: So I might have a module-level logger called `__main__` *and* a root logger, and touch the root logger if, say, I want to attach a `Handler` that hits all my logging?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - i believe that's a good idea. Because - what happens is as follows -

If you are running a program as python prog.py - (the `__name__` would be `__main__`) and you'd get the `root` logger (expected). Or you can even give a name that you'd like (say `prog`). and when you `import` that module - the name would be the name of the module. (python file name without the extension in this case `prog`), which will help you identify the origin of the logs - which is what you'd want. So in general it'd be a good idea to do so.